# isapi rewrite help

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, iis-6, isapi-rewrite

Hi there I have the following isapi rewrite rule working on IIS 6.

it rewrites:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?category=white-wine
```

to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/white-wine
```

**.htaccess contents:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ /?category=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I am now trying to do almost the same rule but in a folder deeper. 
*edit* 
The rule is in the same .htaccess file in the site root i simply want to apply the above rule, to an index.php file that is in a folder in the root called products.

I want to rewrite:

```
http://www.mysite.com/product/index.php?product=the-chosen-product
```

to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/product/the-chosen-product
```

I have tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/product/?$ /product/?product=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This is not working though I get a load of errors on my php page:

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

Warning: require_once(http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/framework/library.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found
```

I was originally getting those errors with the first rule, but as that is working now, I guess it must be possible to do the second rule somehow?

Also how would I change it so instead of displaying:

```
http://www.mysite.com/product/my-chosen-product
```

it would show:

```
http://www.mysite.com/product/my-chosen-product.htm
```

I am really new to this. I have looked through many other posts and I thoroughly confused, particularly as isapi rewrite, I think, works a little differently to mod_rewrite.

Comment: 1) By ISAPI rewrite you mean [heliconTech ISAPI_Rewrite v3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/)? 2) _"I am now tring to do almost the same rule but in a folder deeper"_ You mean you have put this code into .htaccess in `/product/` folder ? If so -- will it be OK if this rule be placed in main .htaccess instead (it's easier to manage and no need to worry about different quirks)?

Comment: 1) yes helicons isapi rewrite 3
2) all the rules are in the .htaccess in the root folder of the site i am just trying to apply a rule to a page which is in a folder in the root, still called index.php with 1 url param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RE:** "Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: URL file-access is disabled...".

Do not use `require_once(http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/framework/library.php)` -- it is forbidden on your server (but even if it would be enabled -- it is not recommended to do it in this way). Use `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myfolder/framework/library.php')` instead.

---

**RE:** Rewrite Rule (for products). Use this instead:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/product/index\.php
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/?$ /product/index.php?product=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

So your whole .htaccess should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?category=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/?$ /product/index.php?product=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I have made some small changes to your rules: specified `index.php` straight away, otherwise IIS would had to figure out the correct script name later .. which requires some tiny but still resources to do so.

---

These rules will work with extensionless URLs (e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/product/the-chosen-product`). If you want to have `.htm` extensions in such URLs you have to do:

a) Generate those URLs in your application straight away

b) Modify rewrite rules a bit: replace RewriteRule lines with these:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.htm$ /index.php?category=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)\.htm$ /product/index.php?product=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

With such changes old extension-less URLs (without `.htm`) will no longer work.

Comment: thanks i will give all this a try out on monday, when i get back to work :)

Comment: hi have not tried them yet as i needed to sort other stuff out on the site first, am going to have a go with them now, i will let you know how i get on.

Comment: rules are working great thanks, at the moment all the links i have on the site are set to use eg. http://www.mysite.com/index.php?category=mycategory
this displays in the address bar as it is it does not get re-written to http://www.mysite.com/mycategory
so i assume i have to have all links in the site to use the rewrite url? is there no way to convert a link typed in as the querystring value to be rewriten to the rewrite value?

Comment: sorry one last thing how would i get it to show a trailing backslash so http://www.mysite.com/product/myproduct becomes http://www.mysite.com/product/myproduct//

Comment: 1) If link is already `/index.php?category=mycategory` .. then you have to generate proper nice URLs in first place (when you generate the page). You can create a rule that will do 301 Redirect to a nice URL if such REAL URL is typed .. but that may be quite complicated task which worth asking as separate question.

Comment: 2) Generate nice URLs with trailing slash in your code in first place. The rule in my answer will handle both with and without slash at the end. To specify proper URL to be used, use `<link rel="canonical" href="PROPER_URL" />` -- this will help SEO and search engines. To force trailing slash with mod_rewrite use this (depends on your URLs actually, so test it well): `# add trailing slash for non-existing resources` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` `RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]`